# Stuck at "Checking for updates". Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, updates

The problem I cannot run updates on a window 7 computer, because it gets stuck at "Checking for updates".
That I have tried:

1. Disabling the antivirus
2. Deleting all contents from the update folder
3. Updating the update client from microsoft.
4. Running chkdsk /f
5. Waiting for a whole day to find the updates.

Nothing seems to work.

Edit:
Found a workaround. No suggestions helped here. So I used this app to get all the updates manually : 
http://www.wsusoffline.net/

Comment: The windows update toubleshooter is worth trying -https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/instantanswers/512a5183-ffab-40c5-8a68-021e32467565/windows-update-troubleshooter. In many cases, it resolves the issue by repairing the update components. I had similar issues, which turned out to be related to my ISPs' routing profile on my account. Updates for Windows come from the Akamai CDN, which throttles certain connections. Try changing your DNS to GoogleOpenDNS (8.8.8.8). If that improves things, you have the cause.

Comment: Improve your formatting by using adding blank line in front of your list. That will actually format it as a list. What specs does the PC have? Does it already have SP1? Did it work before or is it freshly updated?

Comment: This is a common problem with Vista and 7.  It almost seems like Microsoft is attempting to "encourage" users to go to 10, since the automatic background update work chews up the CPU continuously, making the box seem "worn out".  The simple fixes for this problem often don't work -- you need a fairly involved procedure.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - If that was the case Microsoft wouldn't be solving the underline problem with previous versions of Windows, the hundreds of yearly updates, on Windows 7 by releasing cumaltive monthly updates for present, future, and past updates..  Honestly I don't blame Microsoft for putting money to solve the Window Update problems (in other words how Windows Update scans for updates) that exist in Windows 7 and Windows Vista, and instead approach the problem, by releasing less updates by simply combining the monthly updates into a single package.

Comment: Microsoft is the only software company that spent money, to improve a previous version of their product, after they released a new version of that product.  Apple,Canonical, Google certainly do not spend developer resources to improve previous versions of their OS, just because its used by 50% of their user base.

Comment: @Alex - That link is for Windows 10.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Windows 7 version - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2714434. Windows 7 isn't the most stable platform, but I doubt it's deliberate. Microsoft don't care if people upgrade or not, they have a license fee from so many users that it makes no difference. There were fundemental issues in Win7 which were address in Win8.1, but retrofitting fixes into an older OS is always complex. All versions of Windows slow down over time without maintenance anyway, so it's a bit of a moot point.

Comment: @Alex - *All versions of Windows slow down over time without maintenance* -- And why is that??

Comment: @DanielRHicks Disk fragmentation, exponential registry growth, corrupted registry keys, overcomplicated file system, leftovers from installations. Windows is a very compelx system, as are UNIX, Linx and OSX. It just so happens that the Windows platform is more prone to slowdown when it develops bloat. Windows 10 is much better for it though. Compared to NT4 through to XP, Win10 is much less prone to slowdown over time. I'd see that as a sign of progress.

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the latest Windows Update agent as they specifically addressed this issue along with how windows would start running the uodate service even though it was set to manual.  Also, make sure the Background Intelligence Service, Application Identity, and SPP Notification Service are on.  You can check by typing "Services" in your Windows Search bar or by right clicking on your Windows Start menu icon.

If the services are running I suggest resetting Winsock by typing "netsh winsock reset"

Comment: Except that the download of the Windows Update Agent gets stuck in "Checking for updates".